# Redirect to Login page after session expire or idle time in MVC application using ASP.net core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core. I want to redirect to login page when session expires or user is idle for 10 min. How can I achieve this? Currently, logout is happening (as when user clicks on any link or submits button, application gets redirect to login page. This happens when user clicks on button or link.) I want to redirect to happen to login page without user clicking on button or link.

Currently I have written this code in Startup.cs

1. Inside ConfigureServices

   ```
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

        });
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.LoginPath = "/MVCApp/Login";
        });
   ```
2. In Configure

   ```
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapRazorPages(); 
        });
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
   ```

any suggestion on this.

Comment: Normally you would have javascript running on the page very x seconds that would check the session.  You would return true if session stills exists and false if it does not from your controller.  Then based on false you can redirect anywhere you need or display a popup.

Answer (score 6):

you should handle this in client side like this :

```
<script>
(function() {

    const idleDurationSecs = 60;    // X number of seconds
    const redirectUrl = '/logout';  // Redirect idle users to this URL
    let idleTimeout; // variable to hold the timeout, do not modify

    const resetIdleTimeout = function() {

        // Clears the existing timeout
        if(idleTimeout) clearTimeout(idleTimeout);

        // Set a new idle timeout to load the redirectUrl after idleDurationSecs
        idleTimeout = setTimeout(() => location.href = redirectUrl, idleDurationSecs * 1000);
    };

    // Init on page load
    resetIdleTimeout();

    // Reset the idle timeout on any of the events listed below
    ['click', 'touchstart', 'mousemove'].forEach(evt =>
        document.addEventListener(evt, resetIdleTimeout, false)
    );

 })();
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure this works if computer is put to sleep/hibernate and users comes back. To be tested. Thank you for the code.