# window.postMessage() not usng iframe or popup across two unique origins not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My desired outcome is for two tabs to communicate client-side (user interface events like mouse, keyboard, etc.) with each other.

Ultimately, I'm trying to track user input so I can determine if the user has left the application(s) idle and I timeout and close their login session.

We have a "hub" application where the user logs in and then they click on links that open other, completely separate applications, that are hosted on different servers/ports but are signed in via the single sign on process via the "hub".

The "hub" application is a .NET Core 3.1 MVC application in C# while the other applications are .NET Framework 4.8 MVC and Web Forms applications in C#.

These applications open in separate tabs in the browser.

With that said, my goal is to check if the user is idle in any one of the tabs and sign them out. I have a solution now that checks if they're idle at the "hub" but if they tab out and work on application1, the "hub" will time them out and after the timeout, when the user clicks to do something on application1, they'll get the login screen.

I'm not all that conversant with sessions and cookies, so perhaps there is a great session or cookie mechanism that I am unaware of that someone can suggest?

Meanwhile, I have a simple Javascript client-side code that simply checks to see if the user has done something at the "hub" like a mouse move, etc. and resets the idle timer if they do. Otherwise, the "hub" signs them out.

I got this code from another [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71466159/redirect-to-login-page-after-session-expire-or-idle-time-in-mvc-application-usin).

To be sure. I've done the "standard" session timeout stuff in the startup.cs file on my .NET Core MVC web application that [you'd find just about anywhere you search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0). I noted they all basically describe the same set of steps, and I implemented them, and they didn't meet the requirements.

I looked into [four ways to communicate between browser tabs](https://blog.bitsrc.io/4-ways-to-communicate-across-browser-tabs-in-realtime-e4f5f6cbedca), but the same origin restriction is kicking my fanny here. I looked at [Redis](https://redis.io/) as well, but it's not really Windows friendly, and I had success using the [StackExhange](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) distribution in the .NET Core app but not so much in the .NET Framework 4.8 app. The app wouldn't load after I included that package.

Of the four ways, I'm seeing that `windows.postMessag()` declares itself to provide cross-origin functionality (with all the security issues that might apply). However, I'm unable to successfully test this methodology, and I can't find any examples that don't use an iframe or a popup. I'm not using either.

With all that said, if someone has a better idea for solving my core issue, then I'd appreciate the input. Otherwise, here is some sample code:

First, I created two separate IIS sites on my local machine that use SSL.
https://localhost:48062 and https://localhost:48063. This setup best follows my actual usage in 'real life'.

Second, I create two index.html files. One for each site. The first html file opens the second in a separate tab. From there, I attempt to use the `windows.postMessag()` calls.

**https://localhost:48062/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Post Message : Test2
        </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            const openTest3 = () => {
                window.open("https://localhost:48063/index.html", "_blank");
            }

            $(function() {
                console.log("document ready");
                // Note I've used window.addEventListener() as well here
                window.onmessage = (event) => {
                console.log("onmessage");
            }
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test2 Page</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Open Index.html on Test3" onclick="openTest3();" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**https://localhost:48063/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Post Message : Test3
        </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            const DoNothing = () => {
                console.log("Doing Nothing In Particular");
            }


            function resetIdleTimeout() {
                window.postMessage("MouseOver, Click, or KeyDown performed on Test3 Page", "*");
                console.log("window.postMessage called");
            }
    
            function workSessionTimeout() {
                // Set the window events
                $(window).mouseover(() => resetIdleTimeout());
                $(window).click(() => resetIdleTimeout());
                $(window).keydown(() => resetIdleTimeout());
            }

            $(function() {
                window.postMessage("Test 3 Page Loaded", "*");
                resetIdleTimeout();
                workSessionTimeout();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test3 Page</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Click Here for No Action" onclick="DoNothing();" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What happens? I don't get any errors, but I'd expect the message to show up in the console on the first index.html. It's not.

I'd appreciate any insights.

Comment: Have you heard of - or perhaps even tried - [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/signalr) ? By using their libraries in a backend + all front ends, you do not need to reinvent the wheel to communicate in all directions between clients and the server. On the client it is as simple as sending a message through JS to the server + implementing a JS event handler that processes server messages. The content of the messages can be anything you want.

Comment: I've "heard" of SignalR but I've not looked into it. I will now though. Thanks!

Comment: SignalR is your best bet. It's as a general rule rather difficult to communicate with another copy of a web page. If this was easy then when you visit my site to look at a cute cat picture   then my code would hunt around for a browser page doing your on-line banking. So it's not allowed and is far too high of a security risk. But setting up a communication channel does and allows such communication between browser sessions.